# DIsplay User's Information after Logging In Xamarin Android

Tags: android, database, xamarin, authentication

I have a login system where the user have to register and can login after they register for an account. What I am trying to do is to display user information into a new .axml after successfully logging in. Any help will be appreciated. Code is shown below.

MainActivity.cs

```
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Widget;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Gms.Ads;
   using SQLite;
   using System.IO;
   using System;

   namespace LogInApplication
   {
[Activity(Label = "Log In Application", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAds = null;


    EditText txtusername;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btncreate;
    Button btnsign;
    Button btnedit;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it

        interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mAdView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
        var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        mAdView.LoadAd(adRequest);
        //setting unit id for interstitial ad
        interstitialAds.AdUnitId = "ca - app - pub - 3113453000644941 / 8764416112";
        //loading test ad using adrequest
        interstitialAds.LoadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAds.AdListener = new AdListener(this);



        btnsign = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnlogin);
        btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnregister);
        btnedit = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnforgot);
        txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtusername);
        txtPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtpwd);
        btnsign.Click += Btnsign_Click;
        btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click;
        btnedit.Click += Btnedit_Click;
        CreateDB();
    }


    class AdListener : Android.Gms.Ads.AdListener
    {
        MainActivity main;

        public AdListener(MainActivity innerMain)
        {
            main = innerMain;
        }

        public override void OnAdLoaded()
        {
            base.OnAdLoaded();
            main.interstitialAds.Show();
        }
    }



    private void Btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(RegisterActivity));
    }

    private void Btnedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(ForgotActivity));
    }

    private void Btnsign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3"); //Call Database
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
            var data = db.Table<LoginTable>(); //Call Table
            var data1 = data.Where(x => x.username == txtusername.Text && x.password == txtPassword.Text).FirstOrDefault(); //Linq Query
            if (data1 != null)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                StartActivity(typeof(WelcomeActivity));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Username or Password invalid", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
    public string CreateDB()
    {
        var output = "";
        output += "Creating Database if it doesn't exits";
        string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3"); //Create New Database
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
        output += "\n Database Created.....";
        return output;
    }
}
   }
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ButtonLogInStyle"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnforgot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ButtonLogInStyle"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnregister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to show the detail once the user logged in, thing that you could do is creating a `Services` folder and create a static class `GlobalVars.cs` in it. It will be used to put any global variables that you would use. In your case it will be the `Username` (put it after login success), then you could retrieve the data from database again when needed, or create a `User` class and put all the user's detail in it. When you need the variable stored in `GlobalVars.cs`, you will need to simply call `Services.GlobalVars.variableName`

To give you the idea with this approach, I will attach sample of `GlobalVars.cs` that contains `User` variable.

*/Services/GlobalVars.cs*

```
public static class GlobalVars
{
    public static User UserDetail;
    ... //other variables needed
}
```

*AnotherActivity.cs*

```
var DetailFromLogin = Services.GlobalVars.UserDetail;
```

Or

```
using Services;
...
//calling the variable 
var DetailFromLogin = GlobalVars.UserDetail;
```

Of course, by using this approach, you could not save the login credential once the app is closed (as it used local variable to store it). If you would like to save the login credential once the user logged in and perform checking so the users could skip the login page, what I suggest you to use is `ISharedPreferences`. It will save the data in the persistent storage. The data that can be saved there is primitive data, such as int, boolean, string, float, and stringset.  Check it out in this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference).

Hope this could help.

Comment: what am i supposed to put inside user class?

Comment: It is up to you, what data you would like to record from a user? Generally, you would like to record about the username, password, name, address, other information like those.

Comment: How can I insert it inside the User class?